# Parse ACL: Add to existing ACL

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse Object called Hotel with ACLs set to it. There is a function which assigns Manager to the Hotel. So now I want to add the Manager (Parse User) to read write ACL for the Hotel object. Can I just do as below:

```
hotel.setReadAccess(managerObjectId, true)
hotel.setWriteAccess(managerObjectId, true)
```

OR I need to do hotel.getACL() first and then somehow add the new manager ACL to it. (don't know if this is possible)

Comment: have you considered using roles?

Comment: Yes. I have roles namely ADMIN, SUPER_USER. But in this case here I want to exclusively give the user, rights on the Hotel.

Comment: i guess you'd need to get the existing ACL and modify it rather than just adding a new one, otherwise you'd remove all the existing rights. managing it with a role should be easier

Comment: You could also try Pointer Permission, which is a class level permission. Add a new column of type Pointer<Manager> to the Hotel class. Then you can edit the Hotel class's Class Level Permission to give read/write access to the Manager in the Pointer<Manager> column of the Hotel class. This way, the Manager in the Hotel object will get read/write permission to the Hotel Object.

Comment: with the above method, whenever you do hotelObject.set("managerColumnName", managerObject), the manager will have read/write permission to the hotel object.